# Find instances for arbitrary type expression

Tags: haskell, typeclass, ghci

Is there a way to persuade GHCi to tell me what typeclass instances some arbitrary type expression implements?

Obviously, you can use the `:info` command to find all the instances for a *type constructor*. But what about some complex *type expression*?

For example, if I wanted to know what instances `Maybe Int` has (not `Maybe`, but `Maybe Int`), how can I do that?

I tried

```
 :info Maybe Int
```

but that just gives me information for `Maybe`, followed by information for `Int`. It's treating it as two separate type constructors, rather than a type expression.

Particularly when you have complicated monad transformer stacks, it's not always obvious exactly which instances a specific stack might have.

Comment: :info seems to just accept a list, parses each word and displays. I agree what you want would be a nice feature.

Comment: Instances that match `Maybe Int` would include any instance for `Maybe a`, `t Int`, `t a`, and plain `a`. And instances for any MultiParam class of which one type unifies with `Maybe Int`. I doubt that's going to be useful. Or do you mean to exclude instance more general than `Maybe Int`? That won't help you understand why some type at `Maybe Int` gets matched to some instance.

Comment: AntC is right, this feature would be highly nontrivial to implement in an actually useful way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since GHC 8.10.1 there is an [`:instances`](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/9.6.1/docs/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:instances) command in GHCi:

```
> :instances (Maybe Int)
instance Read (Maybe Int) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
instance Eq (Maybe Int) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Maybe’
instance Ord (Maybe Int) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Maybe’
instance Show (Maybe Int) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
```